# RSSI appear as zero

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, rssi

I use a feasy beacon device , with an iOS application , but I face an issue with the RSSI signal ,

if the device is beside the iPhone I receive the signal , but if there is a space between the iPhone and the beacon (from 20 cm to 100 cm) I didn't receive the signal .

my beacon setting is :

interval : 100 ms
TxPower : -19.5
Key (ms) : 100-35000
TLM is On
RSSI at 1m : -3

any recombination to modify the setting to receive the signal on 1 meter distance .

Answer (score 1):

A transmitter power of -19 dBm is very low and won't be detected for more than a few centimeters.  Try a stronger setting.  A typical iBeacon has txPower set to +2 dBm.

When the detected RSSI of an iBeacon signal on an iPhone drops below -90 dB,  it gets reported as an RSSI of 0.  The reason you see this level is because it is barely being detected.

Comment: Hello , thank you for the Answer , I update the txPower to 2.5 (the maximum value in my beacon) , but I receive the RSSI when the beacon is 40 cm away from the iPhone , more than 40 cm I didn't receive an RSSI value , any recommendation ?

Comment: I used 3rd party beacon scanner ( Locate Beacon ) , and the results is the same , I receive the signal on the distances less than 40 cm  , is this issue related to the beacon type , should I change the beacon ?

Comment: clearly the 2.5 setting you applied did not set the transmitter output power to +2.5dBm.  If it did, you should be able to detect the beacon 40 meters away or more with clear line of sight.  I would contact your beacon manufacturer or use a different beacon.